# Android download Audio from server

Tags: android, download

I want to dowanload Audio via url from my server when I click the button.

How I do it ?

Comment: You question not clear. What you want to do ?

Comment: Thanks sir i want to dowanload Audio via url form my server when I click the button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To DownloadFile from server you can use the following code.

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
    int count;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("url of your .mp3 file");
        URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
        conexion.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
        int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

        // downlod the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/somewhere/nameofthefile.mp3");

        byte data[] = new byte[1024];

        long total = 0;

        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;
            // publishing the progress....
            publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
    return null;
}
}
```

**manifest permissions:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Also refer following links it may help you :

[how can i download audio file from server by url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7351940/how-can-i-download-audio-file-from-server-by-url)

[How to download a file from a server and save it in specific folder in SD card in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117067/androidhow-to-download-the-file-from-the-server-and-save-it-in-specific-folder)