# How to download mp3 file from url to Internal storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I made a downloader and it works but the problem is when I download from mobile has no External storage it doesn't work

here is my code which does well for external storage :-

```
lateinit var downloadManager :DownloadManager
lateinit var request : DownloadManager.Request
downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

btndownload.setOnClickLisner{
request = DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri)
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
request.setTitle(songdownloadedname)
request.setDescription(null)
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, songdownloadedname)
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(true)
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

}

**What can I edit to download it to internal storage instead of external one ?**

Comment: The answers of this question may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: so are you getting any error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android download Audio from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161736/android-download-audio-from-server)

Comment: I don't believe you have tried searching before asking, while you have to.

Comment: I used all classes in all answers and it didn't work with me .. so I published the question to get help , shouldn't I ? @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: You have to mention what you have tried, or obviously you will be offered the answers you already tried.

Comment: I already did it cause my question is more specific for what I exactly wanna do @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: No, you didn't . You didn't show what you tried.

Comment: don't you see your question is already closed (on hold) because it is missing what I am asking you to add? You **really have to** add what you have tried. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before starting talking about somebody's eyes.

Comment: Yeah you are right man .. thanks man maybe I have to be more professional when I ask .. and sorry for any misunderstanding @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: No problems. Let me also explain *why you are required to add what you have tried*. If you tried a lot of answers, as you said, it likely means that you did it somehow incorrectly. That's why if you show how exactly you have tried at least something, we will likely find what exactly you did incorrectly. While if you don't show what you tried, you will likely be offered with solutions, you have tried already, and therefore you will just waste time of people who wrote answers.

Comment: I have edited the question Now can you help ?@VladyslavMatviienko

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager) to download file. you can use this [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/) (not my blog) as reference. Source code below taken from the blog:

```
public class DownloadManagerActivity extends Activity {
    private long enqueue;
    private DownloadManager dm;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                            view.setImageURI(Uri.parse(uriString));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Request request = new Request(
                Uri.parse("your mp3 url"));
        enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);

    }

    public void showDownload(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not look like `kotlin`.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko true, but if you check question tag, it also tagged as java question

Comment: you are absolutely right. Could you please add ore remove a space inyour answer so I'm able to remove the downvote?

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. OP asks to storage the data in Internal storage. DownloadManager can only save to external storage.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to check your manifests file AndroidManifests.xml.
(You need to allow your app to connect).

try
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`